# uploading data to table getting no result

Tags: reactjs

hello iam following mosh hamedani course at some point i got stuck  in uploading data in table[image]

this is my table where title and genre is uploading where in stock and rate these are number not string are not uploading  here is my table body

```
class TableBody extends Component {
    
    render() {
        const {data,columns} = this.props
        console.log({data,columns})
        return ( <tbody>
            {data.map(item => <tr key={item._id}>
                
            {columns.map(column => <td key={item._id + (column.path || column.key)}>{_.get(item,column.path)}</td>)} 
            </tr>
            )}
            
        </tbody>
            
        );
    }
}
```

data and columns are coming from movietable component here is the code

```
class MovieTable extends Component {
  columns =[
    { path:'title',label:'Title'},
    { path:'genre.name',label:'Genre'},
    { path:'numberInstock',label:'stock'},
    { path:'dailyReantalRate',label:'Rate'},
    { key: 'like' },
    {key: 'delete' }
  ];
  
  render() {
    const {movies, onDelete,onSort ,onLike,sortColumn,onAdd,deleted} = this.props;
    return (
      <table className="table">
          <TableHeader columns={this.columns} sortColumn={sortColumn} onSort={onSort}/>
          <TableBody data={movies} columns={this.columns}/>
          <tbody>
            {movies.map((movie) => (
              <tr key={movie._id}>
                <td>{movie.title}</td>
                <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <Like
                    liked={movie.liked}
                    onClick={() => onLike(movie)}
                  />{" "}
                </td>
                <td
                  onClick={() => onDelete(movie._id)}
                  className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-warning btn-sm active "
                >
                  Remove
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
          <tbody>
            {deleted.map((movie) => (
              <tr key={movie._id}>
                <td>{movie.title}</td>
                <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <Like />{" "}
                </td>
                <td
                  onClick={() => onAdd (movie._id)}
                  className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-primary btn-sm active "
                >
                  ADD
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    );
  }
}
```

movies from props coming from its parent movies component here is movies component code

```
class Movies extends Component {
  state = {
    movies:[],
    deleted: [],
    genres:[],
    pageSize: 9,
    currentPage:1,
    sortColumn:{
      path:'title',
      order:'asc'
    }
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    const genres =[{ _id:"",name:'All Genres'},...getGenres()]
    this.setState({
      movies:getMovies(),
      genres
    })
  }
  
  handleDelete = (_id) => {
    const movie = this.state.movies.find((x) => x._id === _id);
    this.setState({ deleted: [...this.state.deleted, movie] });
    this.setState({ movies: this.state.movies.filter((x) => x._id !== _id) });
  };
  handleLike = (m) => {
    const movies = [...this.state.movies];
    const index = movies.indexOf(m);
    movies[index] = { ...movies[index] };
    movies[index].liked = !movies[index].liked;
    this.setState({ movies });
  };
  handleReinstate = (_id) => {
    const movie = this.state.deleted.find((movie) => movie._id === _id);
    this.setState({ movies: [...this.state.movies, movie] });
    this.setState({
      deleted: this.state.deleted.filter((movie) => movie._id !== _id),
    });
  };
  handleGenreSelect = genre => {
    this.setState({selectedGenre:genre, currentPage:1})

  }
  handleSort= sortColumn =>{
   
    this.setState({sortColumn});
  }

  render() {
    const { pageSize,currentPage,sortColumn,selectedGenre,movies:allMovies,deleted} = this.state;
    const filtered = selectedGenre && selectedGenre._id ? allMovies.filter(m=>m.genre._id === selectedGenre._id ): allMovies;
    const sorted = _.orderBy(filtered, [sortColumn.path],[sortColumn.order]);
   
    const movies = paginate(sorted,currentPage,pageSize)
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-2">
          <ListGroup items={this.state.genres} selectedItem={this.state.selectedGenre}  onItemSelect={this.handleGenreSelect}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
        <div className={this.getbadgesClasses()}> <p>there are {filtered.length} movies in our data base</p> </div>
        <MovieTable 
         movies={movies} 
         onSort={this.handleSort} 
         onDelete={this.handleDelete}
         onLike={this.handleLike}
         deleted={deleted}
         onAdd={this.handleReinstate}/>
        <Pagination
          itemCount={filtered.length}
          pageSize={pageSize}
          sortColumn={sortColumn}
          onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          currentPage={currentPage}
        />

        </div>

       
       
      </div>
    );
  }
  getbadgesClasses() {
    let classes = " badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.movies.length === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }
 
  handlePageChange = (page) => {
    this.setState({currentPage: page})
  };
}
```

this is my console.log
[image]

Comment: Can you console log your data and link it? Probably the naming is different.

Answer (score 0):

i have give  aerong path to Columns array its like spelling mistake in path